How to capitalize first letter of NewDocumentCommand command result
I'm trying to implement a function to show image. The first parameter is path to image, the second is caption text. The second parameter is optional, when not present it should be equal to file basename with first letter capitalized. That's what I wrote:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{m O{\MakeUppercase \GetBasename{#1}}}
{
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{#1}
        \caption{#2}
    \end{figure}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\GetBasename{m}
{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { / } { #1 }
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Figure{example-image-a}
\Figure{example-image-b}
\end{document}

If I remove call to \GetBasename, then it works as expected.

By taking egreg algorithm, we can write the most optimal code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__intolighther_caption_tl

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{m o}
 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__intolighther_caption_tl {#1}

    \IfNoValueT{#2}
    {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__intolighther_caption_tl
        {
            \text_titlecase_first:n
            {
                \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \use_ii:nnn { \file_parse_full_name:n {#1} }
            }
        }
    }

    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{#1}
        \caption{\l__intolighther_caption_tl}
    \end{figure}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Figure{example-image-a}
\Figure{example-image-b}
\end{document}


That cannot work.
You can use \file_parse_full_name:n that leaves on the input stream {path}{name}{ext} and you can choose the second argument, to which you can apply \text_titlecase_first:n.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{O{}mo}
 {% #1 = options for \includegraphics
  % #2 = /path/to/image
  % #3 = optional caption
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {
    \intolighter_figure:nne {#1} {#2}
     {
      \text_titlecase_first:n
       {
        \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \use_ii:nnn { \file_parse_full_name:n {#2} }
       }
     }
   }
   {
    \intolighter_figure:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \intolighter_figure:nnn
 {
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \caption{#3}
  \end{figure}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \intolighter_figure:nnn {nne}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Figure{example-image-a}

\Figure[width=0.2\textwidth]{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b}

\Figure{example-image-c}[Caption text]

\end{document}

Don't forget the p placement option or you risk that the float queue gets stuck.
I also added options for \includegraphics.

Advantages with this approach? None that I can see.
Disadvantages? You cannot specify a \label if the optional argument is missing.
A different approach would be with a key-value interface. You can easily specify a label in every case. The order in which you specify the keys is irrelevant.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { intoligthter/figure } { #1 }
  \intolighter_figure:VVVVV
    \l__intolighter_figure_pos_tl
    \l__intolighter_figure_opt_tl
    \l__intolighter_figure_file_tl
    \l__intolighter_figure_caption_tl
    \l__intolighter_figure_label_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { intoligthter/figure }
 {
  pos     .tl_set:N  = \l__intolighter_figure_pos_tl,
  pos     .initial:n = htp,
  opt     .tl_set:N  = \l__intolighter_figure_opt_tl,
  file    .tl_set:N  = \l__intolighter_figure_file_tl,
  caption .tl_set:N  = \l__intolighter_figure_caption_tl,
  label   .tl_set:N  = \l__intolighter_figure_label_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \intolighter_figure:nnnnn
 {
  \begin{figure}[#1]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[#2]{#3}
  \tl_if_empty:nTF {#4}
   {
    \caption
     {
      \text_titlecase_first:n
       {
        \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \use_ii:nnn { \file_parse_full_name:n {#3} }
       }
     }
   }
   {
    \caption{#4}
   }
  \tl_if_empty:nF {#5} { \label{#5} }
  \end{figure}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \intolighter_figure:nnnnn {VVVVV}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

References: \ref{withpath} and \ref{withcaption}

\Figure{
  file=example-image-a
}

\Figure{
  opt={width=0.2\textwidth},
  file=/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b,
  label=withpath
}

\Figure{
  caption={Caption text},
  file=example-image-c,
  label=withcaption
}

\end{document}



Could I have single figure macro call with passage of a variable which contains caption value?

@Intolighter See the edit.
